# Is it possible to read headers using Perl HTTP::Async module?

Tags: perl, http, cookies, asynchronous, http-headers

To optimize my **Perl** application I need to work with **async** HTTP requests, so I can handle other operations once the HTTP response is finish. So I believe my only option is to work with [HTTP::Async](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aAsync) module. This works fine for simple requests, but I need to catch cookie header from one response and send it with next one, so I need to read **headers**. My code is:

```
             ...

             $async->add($request);
             while ($response = $async->wait_for_next_response)
             {
               threads->yield(); yield();
             }
             $cookie = $response->header('Set-Cookie');
             $cookie =~ s/;.*$//;
             $request->header('Cookie' => $cookie);

             ...
```

but it's not working, as it ends with an error **Can't call method "header" on an undefined value**. Obviously `$response` is `undef`. How can I catch headers before `$response` gets `undef`?

Comment: Hardly, there are many async HTTP modules.  You might want to look at moving to an event based module like AnyEvent::HTTP or POE::Component::Client::HTTP and handle your responses in callbacks.  You shouldn't need to use POE or AnyEvent for your whole app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while ($response = $async->wait_for_next_response)
{
  threads->yield(); yield();
}
```

Is guaranteed not to finish until `$response` is false.  The only false value `wait_for_next_response` will return is `undef`.  You need to either extract the cookie inside the loop, or cache the last good response inside the loop.

Something like

```
my $last_response;
while ($response = $async->wait_for_next_response)
{
  $last_response = $response;
  threads->yield(); yield();
}
```

should work, although I'm not sure you need the loop at all.  It's hard to tell without a complete program.

Comment: Thank you. Other option I just tested is to put in loop following command: $cookie = $response->header('Set-Cookie') . "***\n" if ((defined $response->header('Set-Cookie')) && ($response->header('Set-Cookie') ne ''));